# How can I change the property once that property has already been passed to a function in C#

Tags: c#

I changed `MyAction` after I pass `MyAction` to `TestMethod`, when I call `t.Next(3)` I hope the changed `MyAction` method can be called, I cannot pass `MyAction` as ref or out, because ref or out are not supported in an anonymous function, is there anyway can archive this purpose?
I know I can change the sequence, first set `MyAction` to a method and then call `t.TestMethod(MyAction)`, but the requirement in the real world is I have to change `MyAction` after I called `t.TestMethod(MyAction)`

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.TestMethod(MyAction);
            MyAction = new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine(1); });
            t.Next(3);
        }

        public static Action MyAction;
    }
    class Test
    {
        Subject<int> sub = new Subject<int>();
        public void Next(int v)
        {
            sub.OnNext(v);
        }
        public void TestMethod(Action action)
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, 2).ToObservable().Concat(sub).Subscribe(p =>
            {
                if (action != null) action();
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `Action action`, you could pass a `Func<Action> actionProvider` as a parameter, and then dispatch it like this:

```
actionProvider()();
```